# "Body is missing" when you didn't confirm inserting a link

Tags: bug, edits, editor, error-message

The message "Body is missing." is annoying. It happens when you want to save post edits but forgot to confirm inserting a link.

[image]

The body was present; the message was neither informative nor helpful.

Can we either

1) correct the message to "Confirm/discard inserting a link before saving" **or**

2) remove the message, allow the user to save their posts and resolve the insertion automatically

?

Answer (score 7):

Judging by formatting, "insert stuff" is meant as a modal dialog, so a more intuitive solution would probably be to disable the save button while it's active.

Comment: but we always have UX.SE...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko There are faded buttons. E.g. in review if you press "Edit"; in elections if you choose an option.